# php curl to get img src value on a page

Tags: php, curl

I want to get img src value on a page if it is
https://www.google.com
then result will be like
https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
https://www.google.com/ff.png
https://www.google.com/idk.jpg
i want something like this!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

# Use the Curl extension to query Google and get back a page of results
$url = "https://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

# Create a DOM parser object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

# Parse the HTML from Google.
# The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
# loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

# Iterate over all the <a> tags
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $link) {
        # Show the <a href>
        echo $link->getAttribute('src');
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Here it is

Comment: To target an element with a particular class, use regex and then use loadHTML func in this answer. Ex: $regex = '/<ul class="image-gallery">(.*?)<\/ul>/s';
  if ( preg_match($regex, $html, $list) ){
   @$dom->loadHTML($list[0]);
  }